# Storing String in a variable in a class file

Tags: c#

This is my class file which contains variables which I need to store.

```
public class general
{
    String imagename2;
    String name;
    public string getimage()
    {
        return imagename2;
    }

    public void viewimage(String imagename){
        imagename2 = imagename;
    }
}
```

I firstly store it to the class file

```
selected = lbFiles.SelectedItem.ToString();
general item = new general();
item.viewimage(selected);
MessageBox.Show(selected);
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

And by the time it redirect to another page, when I retrieve, its null instead of the value

```
public View()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    general general = new general(); 
    viewimagename = general.getimage(); // NULL HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    this.ReadFromIsolatedStorage(viewimagename+".jpg");
   // LoadFromLocalStorage();
}
```

I've been thinking and not sure why it became null.

Comment: Each time you call `new` you're ending up with a new instance of `general` so the one you are storing to is not the same one you are reading from. It's like putting your cash in a cereal packet, throwing it away and then opening a brand new box of cereal and then wondering where your cash has gone.

Comment: Consider adopting a consistent naming convention to make your code easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a *new instance* of the `general` class each time, hence you get a new, shiny, blank set of field values.

Comment: Oh, then how do i not create new and use the existing one :x

Comment: Create one instance at the class level, not a local variable inside a method.  Then refer to that same instance in all cases instead of making a new one.

Comment: Under 
public partial class View : PhoneApplicationPage?

Comment: If that's the class your method excerpts are from, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood how classes and instances of classes work, OOP in general:

You are setting the value of a field in one particular instance of the `general` class - this field will only be set for that instance. When you create a new instance of the class, this is a completely separate, different instance -  so the field will have its default value, which is `null` for a string.

Comment: HMm okay i think i got it, any way round it?

Comment: You need to either store your data to disk or some other medium where you can restore it from, or keep the original class instance around

Comment: Some examples would be nice xD

Answer (score 2):

**Form1**
In the form you want to extract your data from

```
private static string _first;   
public string First
{
    get
    {
        return _first;
    }
}
```

**Form 2**
In the form you want to display your data from Form 1

```
View2 f1 = new View2();
viewimagename = f1.First;
```